# Get Shampoo and Conditioner Out of My Eyes

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, comfort

I, and many others, have got shampoo and/or conditioner in our eyes while taking a shower. Opening your eyes will burn your eyes even more. So that means water won't help. Wiping your hands to get the stuff out will actually hurt your eyes even more.

**What is a hack to removing shampoo and/or conditioner out of your eyes?**

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I stopped getting shampoo in my eyes when I stopped washing my face before my hair. The oils on my face seem to protect my eyes, as long as I haven't washed them away yet. Obviously, you're not invincible, and will stiil need to keep the majority of the shampoo off your face.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure the water in the shower is warm. Now, lean over. Gravity will help get any shampoo that is not yet in your eye out.

If you can endure your eyes being squinted (if not try this with your eyes closed, but it will not be as effective):

- Flush your eyes with water, going from the inside (close to your nose) to the outside
- Get out and dry your eyes with a clean towel; make sure there is no residue left over
- Force yourself to cry; tears are great for getting rid of irritants; sometimes you will already be tearing up; you can also try [making yourself sneeze](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Yourself-Sneeze) which usually creates tears
- Clean your eye area again to make sure you've gotten everything

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks! And good job on getting the role of moderator!

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly a hack for getting shampoo and conditioner out of your eyes, but try avoiding getting them there in the first place.
Tilt your head back as you shampoo or condition your hair and the shampoo and conditioner will tend to drip backwards instead of down your face. For the duration in which the shampoo or conditioner will be resting on your head, try to avoid tilting your head forward. Also, if you feel as if the stuff is starting to get into your eyes, close them, then wet your hands and brush the stuff away.

On the other hand, let's say you manage to get shampoo or conditioner - or even soap for that matter - in your eyes. First, get the water running and cup your hands in the stream. Take this water and gently press it into your face (don't jam it into your face), wiping slightly. I've found that this trick always works for me.

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is face the showerhead and let the water rinse out my eyes. If that doesn't work, then I get a wet or damp cloth and dab it on my eyes to get out the conditioner/Shampoo.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer to your question, but rather a solution: Have you tried to use friendly shampoos that don't cause this? (Disclaimer: I could name dozens of companies who increase their income by claiming they produucts are eye-friendly while they are not.) I have got very sensitive eyes and trying 3 or 4 different shampoos I found one that doesn't cause me any problem. I don't use anything else since then.

(I would name the company, but I'm not sure what's the policy on advertisement. I can, however, assure you that you have a better chance in a pharmacy or a special cosmetics shops then in a general drug store or a supermarket.)